# Distinct/Unique users on conversions event Google Analytics RunReport

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-firebase

So I want to automate and make my own dashboard which combines my own data with Google Analytics[image]

Picture above is data that I want to extract. To achieve it, I'm using this API provided by Google:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport

and using Metrics defined in the API (I'm using custom conversions event). I manage to get total of data logged (yellow circle) but what I want is distinct users that log the event (blue circle). I tried to extract all possible metrics from metrics metadata ( https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/getMetadata)
but can't find all conversions related metrics that extract data I want. I need help